# How to make websocket receive cookie

Tags: http, cookies, websocket, fastapi

I'm trying to make a websocket get a cookie but i don't know how exactly.

I tried with a normal endpoint like /test and it gets the cookie. Websocket doesn't get it. Here is the implementation of the websocket:

```
@app.websocket("/ws")
async def websocket_endpoint(websocket: WebSocket, sessionID: str = Cookie(None)):
    #Token path parameter to enter this socket
  
    sessionID = websocket.cookies.get("sessionID") 
 
    if not session[sessionID]:
        await websocket.close(code=1008)
        #avoid ASGI error
        return
    await websocket.accept()
    await admin.set_websocket(websocket)

    await websocket.send_json(json.dumps(admin.active_rooms))


    try:
        while True:
            await websocket.receive_text()

    except WebSocketDisconnect:
        await admin.unset_websocket()
```

I'm getting None (default value), I've been searching a way to make this possible but i couldn't.(I read that is not a http request but there should be an option to do this)

```
const URL = `wss://127.0.0.1:8000/ws`;
const ws = new WebSocket(URL)

ws.onopen = () => {
    console.log('Conexión establecida');
};

ws.onmessage = (event) => {

};

ws.onclose = () => {
   console.log('Conexión cerrada');
            // Realizar acciones adicionales si la conexión se cierra
};
```

I use mkcert to get a certificate to run on https so I can work with cookies (so i'm running back and front on https)

Edit_1: this is the content of the cookie set

```
response.set_cookie(key="sessionID", value=str(id), expires=3600*2, samesite='none', secure=True, httponly=True)
```